# Why is my function appending to all elements it has previously appended to?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
// Show a popup box and return the value
function showPopup(callback) {
    $('.modal').show();
    $('.save').on('click', () => {
        $('.modal').hide();
        callback($('input').val());
    });
}

// Add a new option to a select element
function addToDropdown(dropdownSelector) {
    showPopup((newValue) => {
        $(dropdownSelector).append(
            `<option value=${newValue}>${newValue}</option>`
        );
    });
}

$('#btn1').on('click', () => {
    addToDropdown('#select1');
});

$('#btn2').on('click', () => {
    addToDropdown('#select2');
});
```

When I click `#btn1` and enter a new value, it is added to `#select1`.

Then I click `#btn2` and enter a new value, it is added to `#select1` and `#select2`.

Then if I click `#btn1` and enter a new value, it is added to `#select1` twice and `#select2`.

Why is this happening? It's like the function is being called for each time it's been called in the past.

Comment: @KirkLarkin I'm adding those click event listeners in the same script as the function declarations, I've edited the post to show that. And great point about adding new event listeners, I should refactor the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.save').on('click', () => {
```

is adding the click event each time when showPopup(callback) is called.

You can unbind the previous click event(if any) and attach it like the following:

```
function showPopup(callback) {
    $('.modal').show();
    $('.save').unbind( "click" );
    $('.save').bind('click', () => {
        $('.modal').hide();
        callback($('input').val());
    });
}
```

Another idea(not a very good one, but quick-easy one) you can use is instead of appending you can replace the html in the dropdown:

```
function addToDropdown(dropdownSelector) {
  showPopup((newValue) => {
    $(dropdownSelector).html( $(dropdownSelector).html() + `<option value=${newValue}>${newValue}</option>` );
  });
}
```

Comment: `off` and `on` are the more modern versions of `unbind` and `bind`.